# Create table with limited to only one record

Tags: mysql, limit

Can we create a table in mysql that limited to only one record. 
E.g.: to enter interest rate. There should be only one record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative option: why don't you keep the *interest rate **by date***?

```
date (DATE, primary) | interest_rate (FLOAT)
```

That way you even have the history of interest rates available, no need to restrict the amount of rows, and you still get the limit of one interest rate per day.

Comment: And on top of this, create a MySQL view that selects the most recent interest rate with LIMIT 1

Comment: Thanks Tom, That's what I already did. "SELECT interest_rate FROM interest ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 1". I just curious of the ability of the limit the number of rows in a table.

Comment: You might be able to write a trigger that automatically deletes the old record from the table once you insert a new one, but that's rather hackish.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that't possible in MySQL but you can do some trick by writing `TRIGGER` on your interest table.

Comment: Thanks guys, actually I am not aware of triggers. Tried to create one for some other purpose but failed.